# Strange Error in Angular cli themes.js:236 Uncaught TypeError: $.holdReady is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

There is a strange Error while i build an app using angular2 and angular-cli.
and the errorr message is:

```
themes.js:236 Uncaught TypeError: $.holdReady is not a function
```

Please find the Image for more details.
[image]

my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "app2.0",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    // scripts here
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    // angular2 packages here
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "devextreme": "^16.2.5",
    "devextreme-angular": "^16.2.5",
    "ng2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`devextreme-angular` has dependency from jquery `^3.0.0`

According to jquery changelog https://blog.jquery.com/
since 3.2.0 jQuery.holdReady is deprecated.

So your solution might be downgrading jquery at least 3.1.1 for example you can use `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to freezy jquery version

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the jQuery version used in your project. I think it's 3.2.0. jQuery has the following bug in this version: [$.holdReady is broken in 3.2.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3573). Despite the fact that `$.holdReady` [is deprecated in jQuery 3.2.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out/), it should not have been removed from the `$` variable. I believe the jQuery team will resolve this issue in their next version. At the same time, DevExpress is also going to fix the issue. See the [DevExtreme fails with the "$.holdReady is not a function" error when jQuery 3.2.0 is used](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T494217) bug report.

At the moment, I suggest you use jQuery 3.1.1 in your project:

`npm i --save jquery@3.1.1`